# BFGS optimization is much slower in Python compared to Octave

Tags: matlab, scipy, octave

I have some code in Octave/Matlab that that performs L-BFGS optimization, with a call signature like this:

```
[optTheta, cost] = fminlbfgs(objFunc, theta);
```

where `objFunc` is my objective function and `theta` is my initial guess for the parameters.  I think `fminlbfgs` is a library, but it's call signature and behavior is similar to `minFunc` in Matlab.  `objFunc` returns `[cost, gradient]`.  This code does a maximum of 400 iterations and completes in less than 5 minutes.

I've ported my code to Python and am trying to use Scipy's `minimize` to do the same optimization:

```
res = minimize(obj_func, theta, 
               method='BFGS', jac=True, 
               options={'maxiter': 400, 'disp':True})
```

But for some reason this code runs extremely slowly (I waited about 15 minutes before killing it).  The return signature of `obj_func` is the same as in Octave.

I'm wondering if maybe I'm not calling the `minimize` function correctly?  Profiling shows that the module containing `minimize` is taking the most runtime.

Comment: Maybe you should compare with scipy's lbfgsb. Without more information it is not possible to tell what the reason might be. There could be some problem with the linesearch that has changed across scipy version.

Comment: Based on the scipy source, I believe `minimize` with `method='BFGS'` should call the same function as `fmin_bfgs`.  It seems like `minimize` is the preferred interface to all of the algorithms implemented by scipy based on the docs.

Comment: I meant `method=‘L-BFGS-B’` which is different from `'BFGS'`, I don't know which optimizer is the equivalent of Octave's `L-BFGS`.

Comment: Ah, I think BFGS is the right one.  I think L-BFGS is a low memory variant which Scipy uses whenever the data is of a certain size or something.  L-BFGS-B is a constrained version of L-BFGS.

Comment: Did you try? bfgs is in Python, lbfgsb in scipy is in Fortran, and might be based on the same originial Fortran package as the one in octave. There is no need to use the last `b` in lbfgsb. But as I commented before, if your optimization doesn't finish in 15 minutes, then something is "weird" in your case.

Comment: L-BFGS-B is a lot faster, but it doesn't seem to be converging.  Maybe there is something wrong with my code, so I'll go back and double check everything again.

Answer (score 1):

I can't exactly point out what your problem is, but you can see whether the BFGS minimization is converging or not by,

```
def print_resnorm(x):
    print "residual norm = ", obj_func(x)[0]

res = minimize(obj_func, theta, 
               method='BFGS', jac=True, 
               options={'maxiter': 400, 'disp':True},
               callback=print_resnorm)
```

Comment: It doesn't seem like this is a convergence problem.  I added a similar print statement to see how many times the `obj_func` was being called, and it was really slow (i.e. each call took substantially longer than it should have).  I'll give this a try though.

Comment: You can also try full newton method or use MATLAB/octave to see if it is a converging problem.